# Sumar ciertas filas en MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla en MySql:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tengo que hacer es una consulta que me devuelva lo siguiente:
adeudo(suma de la columna adeudo), recargo(suma de la columna recargo)
y atrasado(suma de las columnas recargo y adeudo, únicamente de las filas
en donde el recargo sea mayor a 0).

El problema es que no logro obtener la suma correcta en los casos en donde recargo es mayor a 0.

Por ejemplo: en la tabla se tiene una fila en donde el recargo es mayor a 0 por lo tanto la suma deberá ser 394 pero me esta dando un resultado incorrecto 4610.

Las consultas deben ser agrupadas por id_venta e id_producto y en donde el adeudo sea mayor a 0.

El resultado esperado deberá ser el siguiente:

```
adeudo recargo atrasado
4600     10      394
8500      0        0
```

La consulta mysql que tengo al momento es esta:

```
SELECT SUM(adeudo) AS adeudo, 
       SUM(recargo) AS recargo, 
       IF(recargo > 0, SUM(recargo) + SUM(adeudo), 0) AS atrasado 
FROM cuentas_cuenta 
WHERE id_cliente = 2 
GROUP BY id_venta, id_producto 
HAVING(adeudo > 0)
```

Comment: Podes aclarar para ese resultado cuales son las filas que estas sumando?

Comment: @gbianchi cual resultado??

Comment: para lo que decis como resultado esperado, cuales serian las filas que estas sumando?

Comment: Es muy complicado ver los datos en una imagen, podrías publicar una muestra de los datos como texto?

Comment: @gbianchi 4600 de adeudo sale de sumar la columna adeudo de las filas 55 a 66, igualmente recargo suma de la columna recargo de las filas 55 a 66 y atrasado solo seria 10 + 384 = 394, y así se hace para la siguiente fila del resultado esperado

Comment: @jachguate si agrandas la imagen se pueden ver perfectos

Comment: @Jorge, y si estuvieran en texto, no hay que agrandar nada ;)

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre. No jorge, no puedo agrandar la imagen porque te estoy ayudando desde un celular y seria mucho mas facil que me ayudaras a ayudarte poniendo las cosas para que las pueda ver ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo varios puntos con respecto de la consulta:

- Ne cuesta imaginar en que casos sería útil una consulta que agrupe, en donde no se incluyan las columnas por las que se agrupa dentro del `select`, por lo que las he incluido.
- He cambiado la suma del `atrasado` para sumar aquellos dónde hay recargo.
- He eliminado la clausula `having`, pues de la manera en que estaba escrita no tiene mucho sentido. La idea de la clausula `having` es filtrar después de agrupar. Por tanto, he movido la condición al `where`, que es a donde me parece que pertenece, para filtrar antes de agrupar.

El resultado final luce así:

```
SELECT   id_venta
       , id_producto
       , SUM(adeudo) AS adeudo
       , SUM(recargo) AS recargo
       , sum(IF(recargo > 0, recargo + adeudo, 0)) AS atrasado 
  FROM cuentas_cuenta 
 WHERE id_cliente = 2 
   and adeudo > 0
 GROUP BY id_venta, id_producto
```